# Bad Let in Form Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

```
(define (prime max)
  (let ((a 2)))
  (if not(= modulo max 2) 0)
  ((+ a 1)
    prime(max))
  )
```

It tells me bad let in form (let ((a 2))) but as far as I'm aware, the syntax and code is right

Comment: Only the first and last lines are correct. Every line in the actual code contains at least one error. You need to study more.

Comment: Well, at least the first line is correct. Regarding the rest, it's not clear what you intended to do, but the syntax is mostly incorrect, rendering the procedure useless. Time to read your class notes and study harder ;)

Comment: Note that unlike Scheme, Lisp languages have body forms  of zero or more elements. So `(let ((a 1)))` or even `(let ())` is acceptable; you will find it works in ANSI Common Lisp implementations, Emacs Lisps, and all sorts of historic dialects. ISLisp also: see page 35 of the [2007 draft](http://islisp.org/docs/islisp-v23.pdf).    TXR Lisp, [ditto](http://nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-013AF20B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not right. `let` form has this syntax: `(let binds body)` Your bindings are `((a 2))`. Where's your body? You put it outside the `let` form. This raises two problems: `let` is malformed by only having one argument instead of two, and `a` is undeclared at the location it appears in. (Without going into the logic of the code, which is also incorrect, assuming you are trying for a primality test function.)

Answer (score 0):

`let` format is

```
(let ((<var1> <value1>)
      (<var2> <value2>)
      ...
      (<varN> <valueN>))
  <expr1>
  <expr2>
  ...
  <exprN>)
```

Also the general form for calling a function is

```
(<function> <arg1> <arg2> ... <argN>)
```

so your `not` call is wrong, should be `(not ...)` and the call to `prime` should have the form `(prime max)`.

You got the addition "operator" `(+ a 1)` correct but indeed one big difference between Lisp dialects and other languages is that you don't have special operators, just functions. `(+ a 1)` is just like `(add a 1)`: you are just calling a function that is named `+`; no special unary prefix/postfix case or precedence and associativity rules... just functions: `not` is a function `+` is a function.

Lisp "syntax" may feel weird at first (if and because you've been exposed to other programming languages before), but the problem doesn't last long and after a little all the parenthesis just disappear and you begin to "see" the simple tree structure of the code.

On the other spectrum of syntax complexity you've for example C++ that is so complex that even expert programmers and compiler authors can debate long just about how to interpret and what is the semantic meaning of a given syntax construct. Not kidding there are C++ rules that goes more of less "if a syntax is ambiguous and could be considered both as a declaration and as an expression, then it's a declaration" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Go figure.